# ecma script 2015, arrow function syntax error = () =>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

i want to use this function with arrow function :

```
getGeolocation = () => {
  const options = {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    timeout: 5000,
    maximumAge: 0,
  };

  const success = pos => {
    const { latitude, longitude } = pos.coords;
    this.setState({
      location: {
        lat: latitude,
        lng: longitude,
      },
    });
  };

  function error(err) {
    console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
  }

  const geolocation = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    success,
    error,
    options
  );
  return geolocation;
};
```

and my error looks like this: 
`Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (112:17) getGeolocation **[=][1]** () => {`

Any ideas what the problem might be?

Running on `"webpack": "3.6.0", es2015`

Comment: Can you please show your webpack config?

Comment: maybe declare your getGeolocation. `const geoLocation = () =>`

Comment: @Hinrich this my webpack config https://pastebin.com/NRe2bRDS